# How To Scrape data from web when source file doesn't have the content of web page

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I tried to scrape data from [here](http://www.webcollage.net/MainApp/preview-ppp?module=dellbtoc&site=epartner&wcpc=1512144817149&view=live&rcpName=Webcollage), but problem I am facing is that its source code doesn't contain the content which are available on web page. I believe its scripted.

How do I get it? I got the suggestion that to use selenium? Any other suggestion I could get from you guys it would be very helpful. Thanks.

```
With xhr

            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .send

            If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
                Set internetdata = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
                internetdata.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                htmlT = internetdata.body.outerHTML


            Else
                MsgBox "Error" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & .readyState & _
                vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & .Status
            End If

        End With
```

from this code (string) I am trying to get all the text available on web page. But not getting all the content here.

Comment: I would suggest searching for something called fiddler web debugger. It will allow you to see all the requests and responses that occur. Hopefully one of them will contain the information you want. Then you can try to write some code to send the request to get that information.

Comment: If you're using VBA then automating IE might be a good approach.  Likely you're not seeing the content you expect because the page is built dynamically after loading the original response.

Comment: Can we do it using selenium? Or can we not get all the tags (nodes) and go through it one by one ? just a thought but I wouldn't know how to go about it. I most probably be wrong.

Comment: @Tim I am using IE automation it doesn't give me the actual page content as I believe its hidden by Script.

Comment: @garbb I don't think I can get access to this app as I work in office. But definitely can give it a go at my house. but for now I need the real solution using only what I got which is excel.

Comment: What content are you trying to obtain specifically? It appears pretty scrapable to me.

Comment: If you should your current code someone may have suggestions.  Without knowing what you're *actually doing* it's pretty difficult to offer anything.

Comment: I am using very basic code to get the source code,
'internetdata.body.innerHTML = .responseText'                                          
Try to find  "Strong and silent" which is available on the page but not in source page.

Comment: It is available in the source code under the class name `wc-rich-content-description`

Comment: @ Davis Yes in element you could find it, but is not available in source code. I have certain keywords which I want to look in the whole page so I cannot just look into some specific class or id or paragraph. Any suggestion? Am I missing anything here? or is there anyways to go through all the class and ID one by one to look for the keywords?

Comment: Where is your code with which you have tried and failed? At least post here something to get a refined one @Suman Kumar.

Comment: Btw, every single element of that page can easily be accessed using IE. All you need to do is put a little delay to let the webpage load it's content. That's it..

Comment: "I am using very basic code to get the source code" - maybe that's your problem, but if you refuse to post it we'll all lose interest...

Comment: @william sorry william for the hassel I have added the code above for the source code that I am using..is there any other way to go through all the contents of web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should fetch you all the description of each product:

```
Sub Web_Data()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim topic As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.webcollage.net/MainApp/preview-ppp?module=dellbtoc&site=epartner&wcpc=1512144817149&view=live&rcpName=Webcollage"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set html = .document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") ''if you haven't found your data already, just increase the time

    For Each topic In html.getElementsByClassName("wc-rich-content-description")
        r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = topic.innerText
    Next topic

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: In comment `8` you requested about the text within `"Strong and silent"`. Now going through your post again I can see that you expect all the content. What do you wanna grab actually. Btw, to execute the above code make sure to add reference to the library: `Microsoft Internet Controls` and `Microsoft HTML Object Library`.

Comment: @ Sahin Thanks for the effort Sahin, but when I say whole content it actually meant all of it...including heading paragraphs...etc whatever we can see on the page.I wanna look for keywords (I have got around 500 keywords) to look into the web page, I wanna find if that keyword is available on the page, if not available I want to flag that keyword.

Comment: Do you want to get all the content within this class `wc-rich-content-description`? Be specific man!! Your earlier comment is too broad.

Comment: See the update. I've already edited. Btw, did you execute the earlier one?

Comment: sorry if I am sounding too vague, the class name that you have mentioned is too specific I have got multiple web pages, Anyways I am logging out from office, I will get back to you tomorrow. If the class name is consistent (which I didn't notice..oops) with all URLs. I will sign off and rate it answered. Thanks for all the time you gave here:)

Comment: Hi Shahin, Yes I executed the code and it works, this question came out because of my negligence, I would like to thank Shahin for feeding the answer to me by spoon :p. I am an idiot PERIOD!

Comment: No offense meant. Thanks.